# Will form check videos be allowed?

Tags: discussion

Something very useful that many fitness forums support is a place where users can post their form check videos for others to critique (such as the [technique subforum](http://startingstrength.com/resources/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=155&s=213c829ae7d92e414290d2cab2146c90) of the Starting Strength forum). On the one hand, this is a great way to get feedback on your squat technique, POSE running form, yoga moves, etc, and useful as a long-lived resource that others can use for reference in the future. On the other hand, these sorts of posts have the potential to clog up a Q&A site and make all other types of content hard to find.

Thoughts?

Comment: As long as the quality is good and they don't only submit a video. I'd love for the site to have some more audio-visual content

Comment: Totally agree; this would be great to encourage

Answer (score 6):

I think these are valuable and on-topic. One of the main purposes of this site is exercise technique, which lends itself very well to visual description.

I don't think it would "clog" things any more than any other question.