# Creating [form-check]?

Tags: discussion, tags

A community that I've been using to help me at the gym is Reddit's r/formcheck. It is a subreddit dedicated to novice/intermediate lifters posting form check videos and getting feedback.

I was thinking though, I really appreciate the help I've received from Fitness.SE, *can I bring my form check videos here?*

It seems this has been [discussed before](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74/will-form-check-videos-be-allowed) with a +8 on the question and a +6 on the only answer; I agree with this post. Personally, the best way to [*"[improve] your exercise performance or technique"*](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is to get personalized feedback on your work.

The meta-question was asked 8 years ago. Since then, I can find **3** questions (search: `"form-check" is:question`) that have posted in this manner: [Elbow Tension](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5535/form-check-on-squats-elbow-tension), [Stronglifts Form Check](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/25584/technique-improvement-for-stronglifts-form-check), and [Deadlift w/ Form Checks](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/15439/deadlift-relatively-low-compared-to-squat-where-am-i-weak). The first post is a photo. The second post is more of what I think we could use. The third post could be *but they've removed the videos*.

**My thoughts:**

- A lot of beginners and intermediate level individuals could benefit from form checks;
- Form check style questions could drive more people to our site and generate more questions;
- Fitness.SE is currently set up in an OK fashion to implement form checks;
- Stack doesn't currently host video natively (requires another service, e.g. YouTube);
- Risk of videos getting deleted by users makes older questions obsolete?;
- How do you flag *duplicate* form checks? Does that even exist?;
- How do you make form check questions searchable?

**Possible Actions:**

I think we could start by creating a `form-check` tag.

Questions posted to `form-check` would be subject to some form-check criteria and requirements. Maybe these could be set out in meta-post? Things like camera angle/elevation/rotation, minimum intensity (?), required reps (?), uploading platform (?), and # of form checks per question.

`form-check` questions would need to be more than just a title and video. Maybe some sort of self-assessment in the body as well as questions and concerns.

What are the community's thoughts?

Comment: I don't know why it's never really caught on, it's been on topic almost since inception. Probably needs some good boundaries/formats in the tag usage guidelines.

Comment: @JohnP - one major difference that I've seen is that Stack doesn't really support videos natively. I would need to record myself, upload to YouTube (for example), and then link my YouTube videos. Whereas with Reddit, I can simply record myself and then upload my phone's video straight to the Reddit post.

Comment: This is true, unfortunately. There isn't the native support for videos like there is with the automatic imgur upload for pics. That would be a meta request for upgrade on SE overall (probably), and given the current climate, unfortunately unlikely.

Comment: @JohnP - it seems there are a few sites that have enabled embedded YouTube links (Arqade, for one). This could be a feature-request for Physical Fitness. It would make questions look nicer, but it doesn't help with the three-step process though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would love to see form check requests as a steady surge of content for the site. There's nothing stopping people from doing it, but I think the lack thereof is a self-fulfilling prophecy. Without seeing it, people aren't getting the "oh, I can do that here?" revelation. I'm sure if it got started, it might catch on.

Developing a tag for it might be a way to go, but tags are more of an afterthought when writing a question, so I don't think its existence will be an automatic trigger for people to start posting videos.

On the topic of videos though, there is the extra step that we have to go via a third-party website for hosting. I don't really see StackExchange making the leap to video hosting, but the deal they have with imgur is a nice way to outsource it. There are probably similar deals to be made with certain video hosting websites. In such a case, YouTube is probably one of the least likely partners, but there are plenty of alternatives out there that are far better, in my opinion.

Comment: That's a good point -- someone has to get the ball rolling before more people chime in. Do you have any opinions on the requirements for a `form-check`?

Comment: @C.Lange - I don't have any strong opinions on it, no. As far as I'm concerned, it should just quickly explain what a form-check is, and maybe a basic "how to post a video".

Answer (score 3):

Per @Alec, I decided to get the ball rolling -- I could use some help anyways! We now have the first question tagged as a `form-check`: [Bench Press Form Check](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/41628/bench-press-form-check). I think I might try to make a few more of these as I prep for my first power-lifting competition. I'd like to see this catch on and for more people to submit form-checks.

The tag now exists and could use some editing & creating: [/tags/form-check/info](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/tags/form-check/info). I've never edited a tag wiki before so I'd appreciate someone else laying out a skeleton, maybe? I've got some ideas (as listed in this meta post) to contribute.